# Flux returned in RestEndpoint that produces MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE is returning only when full list is processed

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I hope someone can help me or at least point me to the right direction.
I'm only getting familiar with reactive programming, so this concepts are pretty new to me.

Let's assume that I have this RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/states")
public class StateController {
    private final StateService stateService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/stream/{ids}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<State> getConfiguredStatesStream(@PathVariable List<Long> ids) {
        return stateService.getStatesByIds(oddsIds);
    }
}
```

And a Service:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StateService {
...
public Flux<State> getStatesByIds(List<Long> ids) {
        return Flux.fromIterable(ids)
                .flatMap(id -> calculateStateById(id)); // calculateStateById(id) returns Mono<State>
    }
}
```

When I make a request to an endpoint with a lot of ids, I was expecting the stream to work like this:
In flatMap, when State is calculated and returned, it is immediately sent through stream.
Instead, I can see that it first calculates all states and then returns them all in one bulk.
How do I sent a State back the moment it is calculated (reactive way)?

Comment: Could you please try to make such a request via browser and share results? You can try different browsers. I tested similar case locally and it works as expected on chrome and edge.

Comment: Here's a screenshot from chrome's devtools (requested with aprox. 10-20 ids):
https://postimg.cc/mhpJ7vW3
First, it waited for almost 3.15s and then showed everything all at once. When requesting only with a single item in a list -> returns result in 0.3s, so that let's me think that it doesn't emit anything back, until every single item is ready.

Comment: Ok, I believe I've figured it out...
calculateStateById() has a line, where it blocks a Mono. This leads to this type of execution.